# How can I call a clean method before get_or_create saves to the database?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've got a model in Django in which some data is frequently invalid. Usually I call a `clean()` method that I've written to deal with these situations, however, `get_or_create()` seems to call `save()` before I get a chance to call `clean()`.

How can clean my data before `get_or_create()` attempts to write to the database?

Here's the relevant parts of my model:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    optional_attribute = models.CharField(max_length = 250)

    def clean(self):
        if not self.optional_attribute:
            self.optional_attribute = 'Default'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might be more appropriate to [override the `save` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#overriding-predefined-model-methods):

```
class Article(models.Model):
    optional_attribute = models.CharField(max_length = 250)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.optional_attribute:
            self.optional_attribute = 'Default'
        super(Article, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Alternatively, you could use a [`pre_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#pre-save) signal handler:

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save

class Article(models.Model):
    optional_attribute = models.CharField(max_length = 250)

    @classmethod
    def pre_save_handler(cls, sender, instance, **kwargs):
        if not instance.optional_attribute:
            instance.optional_attribute = 'Default'

pre_save.connect(Article.pre_save_handler, sender=Article)
```

If you want to retain your `clean` method, you could simply use one of these techniques and call your `clean` method from within.

Comment: Is there a benefit to using the `pre_save` approach rather than overriding the `save` method?

Either way I'm probably going to just call my `clean` method within one approach. It would be nice to be able to raise a `ValidationError` if that's something I eventually need.

Comment: Not any functional difference between overriding `save` vs. `pre_save` signal that I know of.  Overriding `save` is more traditional-python-esque, `pre_save` signal is more the-django-way.

Answer (score 2):

The `get_or_create` method is just a shortcut. If you want to clean the object, you can write your code slightly more verbosely.

```
try:
    article = Article.objects.get(**params)
except Article.DoesNotExist:
    article = Article(**params) 
    article.full_clean()
    article.save()
```

Comment: Note that the [actual code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/11e6bf9bdfaecd5325686599af5b21b5b945e61c/django/db/models/query.py#L490) is more complicated, since it takes care of the race condition implicit in the simple version above.